# Django: Trying to access the limited no of random question(tell by user) of specific types from the database table

Tags: mysql, django, django-views, django-orm

In my Django Project i have a Topic table , Subtopic Table, Question table ,Opions table and Answer table.
Here Iam trying to access the limited number of random questions of specific subtopics [both the no of questions(limited number of questions) and subtopics are chosen by user].
like below one

[image: user selection]

here is my models.py

```
class Add_Topics(models.Model):
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Add_Grade,on_delete=models.CASCADE,  default = 1)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=40)


    def __int__(self):
        return id
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Add_Topics'

class Sub_Topics(models.Model):
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Add_Grade,on_delete=models.CASCADE,  default = 1)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Add_Topics,on_delete=models.CASCADE,  default = 1)
    videofile = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True, verbose_name="")
    subtopic = models.CharField(max_length=40,  default = 1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subtopic
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Sub_Topics'

class Questions(models.Model):
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Add_Grade,on_delete=models.CASCADE,  default = 1)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Add_Topics, on_delete= models.CASCADE , default = 1)
    sub_topic = models.ForeignKey(Sub_Topics, on_delete= models.CASCADE, default = 1)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image= models.URLField(null=True)
    difficulty=models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'questions'

class Options(models.Model):
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Add_Grade,on_delete=models.CASCADE,  default = 1)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Add_Topics, on_delete= models.CASCADE, default = 1)
    sub_topic = models.ForeignKey(Sub_Topics, on_delete= models.CASCADE, default = 1)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Questions, on_delete= models.CASCADE, default = 1)
    option1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    option2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    option3 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    option4 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Options'

class Answers(models.Model):
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Add_Grade,on_delete=models.CASCADE,  default = 1)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Add_Topics, on_delete= models.CASCADE, default = 1)
    sub_topic = models.ForeignKey(Sub_Topics, on_delete= models.CASCADE, default = 1)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Questions, on_delete= models.CASCADE, default = 1)
    option= models.ForeignKey(Options, on_delete= models.CASCADE, default = 1)
    correct_ans = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Answers'
```

In views.py functions for this logic we have subtopics to be selected and the no of questions(which should be random not the first and last one) from the mentioned subtopic.how can we done this using django ORM

In views.py

```
def selectassess(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        assess=request.POST.getlist("assess")#checkbox values
        quesno=request.POST.getlist("quesno")#no of question req
        subid=request.POST.getlist("subid")# ids in list
        print(quesno,subid) #display result  in form of list
         
        print(assess)#result in form of list
        

        # max_id = Questions.objects.all().aggregate(max_id=Max("id"))['max_id']
        # print(max_id)
        
        # pk = random.sample(range(1, max_id),quesno)

        # sub = Sub_Topics.objects.filter(pk__in=pk).values('id','subtopic')
        # context4={
            
        #     'sub':sub,

        # }
        print(pk)
        return render(request,"assessment.html",context4)
```

in template assessment.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Create Assessment {% endblock title %}

{% block body %} 
<head>
<style>
#assesssubm {

        display: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="/showassess" onclick="assesssubmit();"><button> Select</button></a>
<form  id="selectassess" action="selectassess" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for t in subtopics %}
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="assess" value="{{t.subtopic}}" >
        <label class="form-check-label" for="assess">{{t.subtopic}}</label>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="subid" value="{{t.id}}">
    <input type="number" placeholder="No of ques to be selected" min="0" max="10" name="quesno" width="60"><br>
    
{% endfor %}

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Select</button>
</form>


<h5>Hello</h5>

{% for q in sub %}
    {{q.subtopic}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

how can i get the output for this scenario.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
RANDOM_MAX_NO = 10
subid=request.POST.getlist("subid")# ids in list

ques = list(Questions.objects.filter(sub_topic_id__in=subid))
random_ques = random.sample(ques, RANDOM_MAX_NO)


context4={'random_ques':random_ques}
```

Comment: Why filter `Sub_Topics` by the  `Questions` ids? Should it be `Questions.objects.filter(pk__in=random_ques_ids)`?

Comment: you needed list of questions ?? or Sub_topics ??

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am just a bypasser, not a question's author. But it looked wrong for me to filter one model by a list of another model's ids

Comment: this works but it is applicable for this case, select x no of random questions from subtopics that are checked. But in my case, for example, the user tells bring 2 questions from subtopic having id=2(means subtopic_2) and bring 4 questions from Subtopic having id=3(means subtopic_3). Can it is possible to generate a query for this